# Не получается создать массив структур через указатели

Tags: c

Не получается создать массив структур через указатели. Если создать массивы глобальными - то всё работает, а я хочу научиться передавать массивы из одной функции в другую.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Strack{
    int amount;
    char client[50];
};

void struktura(int *a, char *s, struct Strack *ps){
    ps->amount=*a;
    strcpy(ps->client, *s);
//  for(int c=0;c<5;c++){
//      ps[c].amount=a[c];
//      strcpy(ps[c].client, s[c]);
//  }
}

void Print(int *X, struct Strack *s){
    for(int c=0;c<X;c++){
        printf("%d \t %s", s[c].amount, s[c].client);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){

    int X=5;
    int a1[]={32154, 123123, 234234, 324234234, 56421};
    char *str[]={"Bob", "Vaka-Vaka", "Ron", "Wuka-Wuka", "Tod"};

    struct Strack st[5];
//  struktura1(a1, str, &s);
    for(int c=0;c<5;c++){
        struktura(a1[c], str[c], &st[c]);
    }

    Print(&X, &st);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что не получается-то? Ну, привели Вы какой-то код, в чём проблема?

Comment: не работает, не запускается программа - где то ошибка

Comment: Я компилировал и увидел кучу предупреждений, исправьте их, и заработает

Comment: @Hellraiser Пожалуйста вместо "_не работает, не запускается программа - где то ошибка_" лучше добавить в вопрос конкретную ошибку, которую вы получаете. Если что-то не выводится, так и пишите "_я ожидал увидеть `Hello World!`, а получаю `Ne hello world!`_", или если ошибка на этапе компиляции, то нужно написать, что за ошибка и желательно на какой строчке она вызывается.

Comment: Да Эклипс не писал в какой строчке ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Я так понимаю на этой строчке:

   ```
   strcpy(ps->client, *s);
   ```

   Вы хотели копировать строку `s` в `ps->client`, но `*s` это оператор разыменования, то есть вы передаете `strcpy(char*, char)`.

   А вам нужно копировать строку:

   ```
   strcpy(ps->client, s);
   ```
2. В функции `Print` `X` это указатель на `int`, то есть если вы сделать `X` итераций, то вам опять токи нужно разыменовать указатель.

   ```
   for (int c = 0; c < *X; c++) {
   ```
3. На строчке:

   ```
   struktura(a1[c], str[c], &st[c]);
   ```

   Вы передаете `a1[c]` по значению, а ваша функция `strukture` принимает первым параметром указатель, то есть нужно получить адрес `a1[c]` с помощью `&`.

   ```
   struktura(&a1[c], str[c], &st[c]);
   ```

Вроде на этом всё! :)

Comment: перед `structura` : `#include"string.h"` В `main` : `Print(&X, &st[0]);`

Comment: заработало, Спасибо

Comment: @AlexGlebe 1) я не стал исправлять все варнинги, только ошибки 2) почему? Функция принимает указатель на массив `Strack`, мы и передаем массив

Comment: Функция принимает указатель на структуру, а передаётся указатель на массив структур. По хорошему это даже компилироваться не должно. Плюсовым компилятором и [не компилируется](https://ideone.com/4Re87m), но сишный проглатывает.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл на `c++` нужно писать без `&`. `st` это и так указатель на первый элемент массива, так же как и на `си`

Comment: `st это и так указатель на первый элемент массива` Тогда почему `sizeof(st) != sizeof(&st[0])`?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл пока мне лень я постараюсь найти сайт где написано об этом (т.к. умными словами я не скажу, я просто знаю и все) вы лучше ответьте почему это работает? Я и на `visual studio` и на `gcc` проверил. Хотя [вот](https://foxford.ru/wiki/informatika/peredacha-massiva-v-funktsiyu-i-vozvrat-iz-funktsii-v-s) вроде нашел. Как раз там написано, что `st` это адрес первого элемента.

Comment: Работает потому что сишные компиляторы более лояльны к ошибками, но предупреждения они честно выдают: [vc](https://rextester.com/FXAN64846), [gcc](https://rextester.com/XDF24242). И из предупреждения ясно видно, что `&st` - это указатель на **массив** а не на первый элемент массива: `expected ‘struct Strack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct Strack (*)[5]’`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118873/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: `но я то вам говорю про то, что передавать st это не ошибка` - согласен с вами, если передавать `st`, то он преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент. Я писал, что передавать `&st` - ошибка, потому что это не указатель на первый элемент массива. (Писать в чате не могу, извините)

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл ну так да это ошибка :) просто видимо изначально высказался не совсем точно